# Preencher Spinner e ListView - Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com Fragment. Tenho dois fragments, onde em um existe uma ListView e no outro uma Spinner.

A ListView e a Spinner é populada com dados que vem do banco de dados.

Durante a depuração percebi que quando chega no método setAdapter: listView.setAdapter(adapter) ou spinner.setAdapter(adapter) é gerado um erro e entra no bloco Catch(Exception).

O erro que dá é o seguinte:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
```

Já acompanhei a depuração, os dados estão vindo do banco de dados, tá tudo correto mais para nesta linha do catch(Execption).

Nos dois casos (preenchimento de Spinner e ListView) o erro é mesmo.

Segue o código do OnCreateView:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View mae = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_usar_produto, container, false);
    spProduto = (Spinner)mae.findViewById(R.id.spProduto);
    npQuantidade = (NumberPicker)mae.findViewById(R.id.npQuantidade);

    npQuantidade.setMinValue(0);
    npQuantidade.setMaxValue(1000);
    npQuantidade.setValue(30);
    npQuantidade.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);

    preencherSpinner();


    btAtualizar = (Button)mae.findViewById(R.id.btAtualizar);
    btAtualizar.setOnClickListener(atualizar);


    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_usar_produto, container, false);
}
```

Agora ó código do método para preencher o Spinner

```
   public void preencherSpinner()
{
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append("SELECT * FROM validade ORDER BY produto");

    Validade val = new Validade();

    cursorProdutos = val.listarProduto(getActivity().getBaseContext());

    ArrayList<String> listaProdutos = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (cursorProdutos.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            listaProdutos.add(cursorProdutos.getString(1));
        } while (cursorProdutos.moveToNext());
    }

    try
    {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listaProdutos);

        spProduto.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.d("exceção", ex.getMessage());
    }


}
```

Comment: Ressalto que o mesmo código acima está funcionando normalmente quando implemento direto em uma Activity. O erro acontece quando está dentro de um fragment.

Comment: `R.id.spProduto` é um spinner? Existe no layout  *fragment_usar_produto*? Note também que o método `onCreateView()` deve retornar `mae` e não `inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_usar_produto, container, false);`

Comment: O Erro era este, deveria retornar mãe ao invés de inflater.inflate....